# e1000 driver update with interfaces gone

Tags: networking, rhel

Intel server with 3 LAN cards.

```
 Board Mfg             : Intel
 Board Product         : S5000PHB  

06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
06:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 80003ES2LAN Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 01)
07:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 80003ES2LAN Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 01)
08:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82546GB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
08:03.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82546GB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
```

Previous driver:

```
root@server2[/root]#modinfo  e1000
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.18-53.el5PAE/kernel/drivers/net/e1000/e1000.ko
version:        7.3.20-k2-NAPI
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <linux.nics@intel.com>
```

Downloaded version 8 and installed in a regular way following the README of the driver:

```
root@server2[/var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src]#make install
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.18-53.el5PAE/build SUBDIRS=/var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-53.el5-PAE-i686'
  CC [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000_main.o
  CC [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000_82540.o
  CC [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000_82542.o
  CC [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000_82541.o
  CC [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000_82543.o
  CC [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000_mac.o
  CC [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000_nvm.o
  CC [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000_phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000_manage.o
  CC [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000_param.o
  CC [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000_ethtool.o
  CC [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/kcompat.o
  CC [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000_api.o
  LD [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST
  CC      /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000.mod.o
  LD [M]  /var/tmp/e1000-8.0.35/src/e1000.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-53.el5-PAE-i686'
gzip -c ../e1000.7 > e1000.7.gz
# remove all old versions of the driver
find /lib/modules/2.6.18-53.el5PAE -name e1000.ko -exec rm -f {} \; || true
find /lib/modules/2.6.18-53.el5PAE -name e1000.ko.gz -exec rm -f {} \; || true
install -D -m 644 e1000.ko /lib/modules/2.6.18-53.el5PAE/kernel/drivers/net/e1000/e1000.ko
/sbin/depmod -a || true
install -D -m 644 e1000.7.gz /usr/share/man/man7/e1000.7.gz
man -c -P'cat > /dev/null' e1000 || true
No manual entry for e1000
```

After that ran **rmmod e1000** and **modprobe e1000**. All configuration files are still where they were.
**lsmod** shows the module is loaded.

Modinfo shows new version of the driver.

```
root@server2[/]#modinfo  e1000
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.18-53.el5PAE/kernel/drivers/net/e1000/e1000.ko
version:        8.0.35-NAPI
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <linux.nics@intel.com>
```

But only eth0 and eth1 interfaces are now available. So eth2,eth3,eth4 and eth5 are gone now.

```
root@server2[/]#service network restart
Shutting down interface bond0:                             [  OK  ]
Shutting down interface bond1:                             [  OK  ]
Shutting down loopback interface:                          [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:                            [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface bond0:  e1000 device eth2 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
                                                           [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface bond1:  e1000 device eth3 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
                                                           [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth4:  e1000 device eth4 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
                                                           [FAILED]

root@server2[/sys/class/net]#ls -la 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 0 Feb 17 17:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 0 Feb 17 10:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 0 Feb 17 10:40 bond0
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 0 Feb 17 10:40 bond1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Feb 17 10:40 bonding_masters
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 0 Feb 17 17:22 eth0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 0 Feb 17 17:22 eth1
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 0 Feb 17 10:40 lo
```

Reboot did not help. dmesg show no attempt to bring any other interfaces:

```
root@server2[/root]#dmesg | grep -i eth
e1000: eth0: e1000_probe: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
e1000: eth1: e1000_probe: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.1.2 (January 20, 2007)
bonding: bond0: Unable to set eth0 as primary slave as it is not a slave.
bonding: bond0: Adding slave eth0.
bonding: bond0: enslaving eth0 as a backup interface with a down link.
bonding: bond0: Setting eth0 as primary slave.
e1000: eth0: e1000_watchdog_task: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
bonding: bond1: Unable to set eth3 as primary slave as it is not a slave.
bonding: bond1: Adding slave eth1.
bonding: bond1: enslaving eth1 as a backup interface with a down link.
bonding: bond1: Unable to set eth3 as primary slave as it is not a slave.
e1000: eth1: e1000_watchdog_task: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
bonding: bond0: link status definitely up for interface eth0.
bonding: bond0: making interface eth0 the new active one.
bonding: bond1: link status definitely up for interface eth1.
bonding: bond1: making interface eth1 the new active one.
```

I spent a lot of time trying to make it work. Can't remember all the things I've tried.
I would be greatfull for any suggestions, tips or information on how the system brings up network interfaces and what could be the reason of not doing it now.

Comment: Take a look at `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, which normally associates your network interfaces.

Comment: Did it. No file.

Comment: There is no /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules file?

Comment: Nope. System doesn't create it. Even after rollback to older driver I see all interfaces, but no persistent file created under udev.

Comment: See https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/. Apparently there are a bunch of different ways this can go.